# How to unzip into specific directory without recreate all the path with bash script

Tags: bash, command-line, unzip

In my ios application, I need to unzip an archive that is placed into /var/mobile/Library/Preferences/xxx into, for example, /var/mobile/Library/Preferences/tmp.

My issue is that when I launch this:

```
unzip /var/mobile/Library/Preferences/xxx/archive.zip -d /var/mobile/Library/Preferences/tmp/
```

in the tmp folder, there is all the archive path: /var/mobile/Library/Preferences/tmp/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/xxx/archive/...

How could I do for only have /var/mobile/Library/Preferences/tmp/archive/... and not all the archive path into the target directory ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I know I can mv the unzipped directory after the first command into a less long path but I would like to not have all this long path to manipulate...

Comment: A bit risky option: `ln -s /var/mobile/Library/Preferences/tmp/ /var/mobile/Library/Preferences/xxx/archive; unzip /var/mobile/Library/Preferences/xxx/archive.zip -d /`

Answer (score 16):

Try the `-j` option to `unzip` which flattens the directory structure and writes all the files into the current directory.

Comment: I've tryed this but the issue is that into my archive.zip there is several folder, I want to keep the internal structure of the archive but not the archive path