# Do not create directories before unzipping

Tags: linux, bash, unix, unzip

First of all, please forgive my spelling errors.
I'm a Frenchy, trying to improve my English speaking (and writting).

I'm looking for a way to unzip a specific file, containing several directories (with more subdirectories) without doing anything if those directories do not exist a destination.

**For example :**

*Archive :* dest.zip

- A1/A2/ficA1.txt
- A1/A2/ficA2.pdf
- B1/shellX.sh
- ...

My destination folder would be : "DEST".

If "DEST/A1/A2" does not exist, I would like to be able to eiter :

- Skip the file, but keep unzipping
- Do nothing, and stop unzipping

Do you know if there would be a way to do so ?

Thanks,

Arkoss

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software tech support.

Comment: See: [How to unzip into specific directory without recreate all the path with bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26212123/3776858)